# error during build process in package.json

Tags: css, npm

In the build process, i am trying to run all of them using the `npm run build:css` command. However, i get an error as shown below. i have performed `npm cache clean --force` but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

[image]

```
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! trillo@1.0.0 prefix:css: `postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.compile.css -o css/style.prefix.css`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the trillo@1.0.0 prefix:css script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-25T16_21_55_998Z-debug.log
    ERROR: "prefix:css" exited with 1.
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! trillo@1.0.0 build:css: `npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the trillo@1.0.0 build:css script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-25T16_21_56_073Z-debug.log
```

how do i fix this issue?

Comment: Please don't include code as image, prefer copy/paste

Answer (score 1):

The `postcss` command in your `prefix:css` script seems to be failing. Make sure the command and the arguments are correct.

Comment: the commands and arguments are correct.

Comment: @AbhinavK what happens when you run that command directly in console